# Overload index operator to mimic POD multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I have an existing class, which is structured in the following way:

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    float Data[4][4];
    // ... methods
};
```

And subsequently used in the following ways:

```
Matrix m;
m.Data[0][0] = 1.0f;
float local = m.Data[0][0];
//...
```

I would like to replace the `Data` member with an overloaded indexing operator, so I can perform range checking on the indices used. While I can change the `Matrix` class itself, and the implementations of its member functions, I cannot modify its usages in existing code, so any solution requires that the usage syntax remains identical. It's also desirable that the solution doesn't change `sizeof(Matrix)`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You'll need several levels of indirection, it's only possible to overload one indexing operator per class.

Comment: yes, I understand that - however, since it's known that it's a 2D array, the indexing operator for Matrix could return some sort of interface, which could also override its indexing operator? ... not sure exactly how it would be structured, if it's in fact possible.

Comment: BTW, how you want to actually store the data? If each row still will be consecutive in memory, you can just overload one `operator[]` to return `float*` --- the address of row start --- and the second `[]` will be handled automatically.

Comment: @Petr the problem is range checking for the second index.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for, you want it to be used exactly the same way : `m.Data[][]`, and `Data` would be a struct with `operator[]` overloaded ? if so, What for ?

Comment: @AntonSavin, oh, did not notice this.

Comment: Your first [] returns an instance of a class that returns an item on [].  When you create the instance you pass a pointer to the row.  You can range check if you instantiate the returned instance with the row size.  Or... you could just write a function at(x, y), which to be honest would be completely clear and wouldn't require a temporary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is define a the proxy class with the semantic of a vector

```
 class Matrix
{
public:
    struct SubMatrix
    {
        class Vector
        {
        public:
            Vector(float *data) : Data(data) {}
            float &operator[](int index) { return Data[index]; }
        private:
            float *Data;
        };
        Vector operator[](int index)
        {
            return Vector(Data[index]);
        }
        float Data[4][4];
    };
    SubMatrix Data;
    // ... methods
};
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
Matrix m;
float f = m.Data[1][2];
```

Comment: As with the other answer, this requires a changing of the syntax - `m[1][2]` instead of `m.Data[1][2]`.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito This way you can keep the syntax

Comment: But what's preventing you from changing that code, too? In any case, you can still use the same techniques that I or marom described while maintaining your `.Data` syntax, if you really want to.

Comment: @celticminstrel - not all the code is under my control. I've accepted this answer, I think it gives the most succinct solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Generally for this sort of thing, you need to use a proxy class to handle the second indexing operator. It would look something like this and go in the `private` section of your `Matrix` class. I'll leave out the bounds-checking (it shouldn't be hard for you to add that yourself).

```
class Proxy {
    Matrix& ref;
    size_t i;
public:
    Proxy(Matrix& on, size_t i) : ref(on), i(i) {}
    float operator[] (size_t j) {
        return ref.Data[i][j];
    }
};
```

Then just have your `Matrix::operator[]` return an instance of this class:

```
Proxy operator[] (size_t i) {
    return Proxy(*this, i);
}
```

Note that if you want a const overload (ie, you want to use the indexing operator on `const Matrix` objects), you'll need a separate ConstProxy class which has `const Matrix& ref` instead of `Matrix& ref` but is otherwise identical.

---

There is also the option of returning a reference to an array. (Note: as one of the comments pointed out, this doesn't help much with bound-checking, but I think it's interesting, so I'll leave it here.)

```
float (&operator[](size_t i))[4] {
    return Data[i];
}
```

The syntax for that is quite arcane, and I believe it doesn't work in Visual Studio 2013, but you can make it a bit cleaner with a typedef.

```
using Proxy = float[4];
Proxy& operator[](size_t i) {
    return Data[i];
}
```

---

There's one more option, if you don't mind abandoning square-bracket indexing. You can overload the function call operator like this:

```
float operator()(size_t i, size_t j) {
    return Data[i][j];
}
```

Comment: For the second syntax, why don't you just return `float*`? Anyway it would not help in bound checking.

Comment: By returning an array reference, the size of the array is remembered. This means you can do something like `for(float n : my_matrix[i])`, for example. If you return `float*`, the size is lost.

Comment: Also, using a reference generalizes better to higher-dimensional arrays.

Comment: part of the complication here is that it's not really `Matrix::operator[]` that I need to overload, it's actually the `Data` object itself, so this isn't quite correct.

Comment: Then you'd need a new class (for sake of example, let's call it `MatrixData`) which uses the same technique. Then you'd declare `Data` to be of that class - `MatrixData Data;`. This is rather an unnecessary level of indirection though, so if at all possible I'd suggest just overloading `Matrix::operator[]` like described, rather than going through the hoops to be able to still access using `m.Data[i][j]` syntax.